# If $f:D\to D’$ is analytic and $u: D'\to R$ is harmonic then the composition of $u$ and $f$ is harmonic in $D$

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f:D\to D’$ is analytic and $u: D'\to R$ is harmonic then the composition of $u$ and $f$ is harmonic in $D$.

How can I show that the above statement is true/false? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is $f$ an analytic vector field?

Comment: Why should? Of $D = D' = \mathbb R^d$, then $u = \mathrm{id}$ is harmonic, but not any analytic function $f = f \circ u$ is.

Comment: @martini: The OP is looking at $u \circ f$. $u=\text{Id}$ doesn't make sense here...

Comment: This question was already discussed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151827/composition-of-a-harmonic-function)...

Answer (score 2):

Locally every harmonic function $u$ is the real part of an analytic function $g$, so locally $u \circ f = \operatorname{Re} (g \circ f)$ is the real part of an analytic function, hence harmonic. A function which is everywhere locally harmonic is globally harmonic, showing that the statement is true.