# Invariance of curvature under a conformal mapping

Tags: riemannian-geometry, riemann-surfaces, complex-geometry

Let $\Omega_{1}, \Omega_{2} \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ be bounded domains. Let $\rho$ be a metric on $\Omega_2$ and $h: \Omega_1 \rightarrow \Omega_2$ a conformal mapping. Let $$h^*\rho(z) = \rho(h(z))\cdot|h'(z)| $$ be the pullback metric on $\Omega_1$. According to the definition I have been given, the curvature on $(\Omega_2,\rho)$ is

$$K_{\Omega_2,\rho}(z) = -\frac{\Delta \log(\rho(z))}{\rho(z)^2}$$

It is then claimed that $K_{\Omega_1,h^*\rho}(z) = K_{\Omega_2,\rho}(h(z))$, i.e.

$$ -\frac{\Delta \log(\rho(h(z))\cdot|h'(z)|) }{(\rho(h(z))\cdot|h'(z)|)^2} = -\frac{\Delta \log(\rho(h(z)))}{\rho(h(z))^2}$$

I cannot derive this result however, and quite frankly I find it dubious. Is it true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. We can get rid of $|h'|$ under the logarithm, since $\log |h'|$ is harmonic.
2. The composition of a function ($\log \rho$ in this case) with a conformal map $h$ multiplies the Laplacian by $|h'|^2$. This is shown in one line [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/151833/53153).
3. By definition of pullback, the denominator is multiplied by $|h'|^2$ too. So $|h'|^2$ cancels, and we are done.

Answer (score 2):

The calculation is fairly painful. I think that Theorem 2.5.4 of [this](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_KM7xCfSwolVThBUW83Szh3dW8/edit) should do the trick.

Comment: but it hurts so good...

Answer (score 0):

By using the pullback metric  $h^*[\rho ds]$ on  $\Omega_1$, you turn the map  $h:(\Omega_1, h^*[\rho ds])\to (\Omega_2, \rho ds)$ into a metric space isometry, and the notion of curvature is a geometric invariant.  So necessarily the two are equivalent (and there is NO computation to do!:-)

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! There seem to be two assertions in play here: (i) A $2$-dimensional Riemannian metric possesses a geometric invariant called _curvature_; (ii) A certain analytic expression in a conformally-flat metric computes the curvature. As I read it, the OP was effectively asked to establish (ii) by showing explicitly that the analytic expression is invariant under a conformal transformation of the domain. Your answer is certainly the elegant conceptual interpretation, however. :)