# Maps in $\mathbb{R}^n$ preserving harmonic functions

Tags: reference-request, harmonic-functions

A map $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ preserves harmonic functions if $f\circ\varphi$ is harmonic for every harmonic function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$.

It is known that these maps are, in fact, compositions of isometries and dilations.

I am looking for a concrete reference of this result, because I only have the reference included in [Composition of a harmonic function with a holomorphic function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151827/composition-of-a-harmonic-function/151941#151941) where the bakground is Riemanian Manifolds. In spanish, we say that this is "matar moscas a cañonazos" (to kill a fly with a cannon). I mean, I have the feeling that this is a classical result of harmonic fuicntions, but I haven't found a "classical" reference.

Comment: Hmm, for the case $n = 2$, every $\varphi$ corresponding to a holomorphic (or antiholomorphic) function preserves harmonic functions. If you demand that $\varphi \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is bijective, then that restricts the candidates to $z \mapsto az + b$ resp. $z \mapsto a\overline{z}+b$, $a \in \mathbb{C}^\ast$, so it works then.

Comment: I'm sorry. I forgot that $n>2$. For the "complex case" ($n=2$) armonic preservin maps are conformal maps.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446841/diffeomorphisms-preserving-harmonic-funtions might interest you.