# Diffeomorphisms preserving harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, differential-geometry, harmonic-functions

I'm looking for smooth maps $ \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb
 R^n $ with the property that, whenever $ h $ is a harmonic function ($\Delta  h=0$), $ h\circ f $ is also harmonic. Is there a nice characterization of these functions? I'm especially interested in those function which are bijective such that $ f^{-1} $ also has this property. Is there a complete characterization of these "harmony preserving diffeomorphisms"?

Comment: Do you mean for $h$ to be a mapping from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes________________

Comment: In the $n=2$, you can $f$ to be any "conformal map" - which is a complex differentiable map with non-zero derivative, as the composition of harmonic and analytic functions is harmonic.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/436115/maps-in-mathbbrn-preserving-harmonic-functions

Comment: I know. The problem is meant as a generalization of this fact to higher dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are ***harmonic morphisms***: maps $\varphi$ that "preserve [Laplace's equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_equation) $\Delta u=0$" upon precomposition by $\varphi$. There is a [vast literature](http://www.maths.lth.se/matematiklu/personal/sigma/harmonic/bibliography.html) on them (they are more generally defined between arbitrary [Riemannian manifolds](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemannian_manifold) using the [Laplace-Beltrami operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%E2%80%93Beltrami_operator)).

In particular with Euclidean spaces, we have this characterization: a map is a harmonic morphism if and only if it is itself harmonic and "horizontally weakly conformal," meaning its components' gradients are orthogonal and equal length. Finding all harmonic morphisms between arbitrary open subsets of Euclidean spaces is an open problem. See Proposition $1.10$ in Wood's reference article [Harmonic Morphisms Between Riemannian Manifolds](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.139.7551). Wood & Helein have a broader-purpose article [Harmonic Maps](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~helein/articles/Hamaps-hbk.pdf) in the text *Handbook of Global Analysis*.

Comment: The characterization of harmonic morphisms as harmonic + horizontally weakly conformal works in Riemannian manifolds too. One more source is the book *Harmonic morphisms between Riemannian manifolds* by Baird and Wood -- not free, but comprehensive and easy to read, with lots of examples and aside remarks.