# maps that preserve harmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, potential-theory

Is there a theory of the type of maps between domains that preserve harmonic functions?  For instance, in the 2-dimensional case, we know that conformal maps (or even just holomorphic ones) are such maps.  But what about higher dimensions, and what about other maps in this class of harmonic-function preserving maps?

In 2-d, We know for instance that any function that is conjugate analytic also preserves harmonic functions, and therefore as is any analytic function of $\overline{z}$.  But are there others?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446841/diffeomorphisms-preserving-harmonic-functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such maps are called *harmonic morphisms*.  I recommend the book [Harmonic Morphisms Between Riemannian Manifolds](http://books.google.com/books?id=GbwinwEACAAJ) by Baird and Wood.

To your specific question: a harmonic morphism $f$ from $U\subset \mathbb C$ to $\mathbb C$ is either holomorphic or anti-holomorphic. Indeed,  $f$ is  a harmonic morphism if 
$$h_{z\bar z}=0 \implies (h\circ f)_{z \bar z}=0 \tag{1}$$ 
We can allow complex-valued $h$ here, since $h$ enters (1) linearly anyway. Using $h(z)=z$ yields $f_{z\bar z}=0$. Using $h(z) = z^2$ yields
$$
(f^2)_{z \bar z} = 2 f f_{z \bar z} +2 f_z f_{\bar z} = 2f_zf_{\bar z}
$$
Since $f_z$ is holomorphic and $f_{\bar z}$ is antiholomorphic, both of them are either identically zero or have a discrete zero set. Since $f_zf_{\bar z}\equiv 0$, it follows that one of the  factors is identically zero.