# Proving a function is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $f(z)=e^{1/z}$ is analytic, except when $z = 0$

---

Since $$\Delta f = \bigtriangledown ^2f = \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2} $$
my guess is that I should try to express $f(z)$ in terms of $x + iy$?
Thanks for your time

Comment: What is expansion of $e^{\frac1z}$.?

Comment: @MyGlasses 
$$e^{\frac{1}{z}} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{z^nn!}$$
and from what I looked up, that must be equal to its Taylor series, right?

Comment: Are you supposed to show directly that $e^{1/z}$ is harmonic for $z\ne 0$?

Comment: See e.g. [Composition of a harmonic function with a holomorphic function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/151827/composition-of-a-harmonic-function-with-a-holomorphic-function) for a general result

Comment: $\exp$ is an entire function, and $1/z$ is analytic except at $0$, so...

Comment: You have to prove that a function is holomorphic or analytic first before you can conclude that it equals its Taylor series. That's why the definition "analytic" exists, because not all functions equal their Taylor series.